# How does this preposition fit in?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I stumbled when read this sentence:

> All seven episodes of Anne With an E are penned by a screenwriter who knows from darkness, Breaking Bad’s Moira Walley-Beckett.
>
> ([source](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/television/2017/05/netflix_s_anne_with_an_e_reviewed.html))

The prepositional phrase "from darkness" does not seem to fit here. Is this an error or am I being thick?

Comment: “to know from X” is an idiom meaning they really know that subject well.

Comment: I suspect it derives from the old saying “you don’t know your ass from a hole in the ground.” but i’ve never tried to verify it.

Comment: "know from" is an idiom--https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220193/meaning-and-derivation-of-so-and-so-would-know-from-x.  Here's an answer that's close to a duplicate.  Basically it means "know about".  It's not ordinary speech; a little bit "in" slang.

Comment: Or maybe from the “I don’t know you from Adam”

Comment: In the OP's phrase, the meaning is that the screenwriter is well-acquainted with the dark side of things.