# How legitimate is the phrase "from which one to choose"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Here's an example.

> If you want to get a PC and you don’t know from which one to choose, choose something simple.

It doesn't look consistent logically, but another person insists this is the correct form. I find it irregular because it's not exactly a choice if there is only one of... well, anything to choose from.
Is that phrase really better than either of the following examples?

> If you want to get a PC and you don’t know which one to choose, choose something simple.

or

> If you want to get a PC and you don’t know from which to choose, choose something simple.

Comment: For a discussion of how "know from" is used in Yiddish English, see [Meaning and derivation of 'so-and-so would know from X'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220193/meaning-and-derivation-of-so-and-so-would-know-from-x). In a standard English version of the sentence you ask about, the wording would be "and you don't know which one to choose."

Comment: The word "know" actually has little relevance in this case. It's all about "from which one," which I find questionable.

Comment: You can choose "which one" to buy, or choose which one "from" the collection of available offerings, but you can't choose "from which one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"from which one to choose" isn't idiomatic English and doesn't make sense: you can't choose from one.

You have to choose (or select, or pick) from a collection, or a set--from more than one, in other words.

choose from those offered in the store

choose something simple (from those offered or from those available)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought, too, but since I'm not a native speaker, I couldn't be 100% sure I was right.